# TCP пакеты приходят группами

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, tcp, python-3.6

Есть задача - измерить скорость низкоскоростного загруженного канала с помощью TCP. Программа написана, в обычных сетях работает как положено. Но в той сети, для которой она собственно создавалась, происходит такое:

После первого пакета, все последующие приходят "кучками", по несколько десятков за одно мгновение, и при этом все, кроме первого в каждой "куче", с практически нулевыми дельтами, при ожидаемых около 30с.

По ощущениям пакеты приходят не по порядку, но тк это TCP, то система просто не выдает их, а когда приходит нужный пакет, то все последующие выдаются моментально и в дельту записывается только время обработки, а не время доставки.

К слову, информация в пакетах сохраняется. Размер пакетов 100 байт. Среднее ожидаемое время доставки 30-40 секунд. Дельта первого пакеты в начале каждой "пачки" +- соответствует ожидаемому времени.

На данный момент замеряю так:

```py
start_time = time.time()
sock.recv(size)
end_time = time.time()
```

Думал класть в пакет время отправки, но проблему это ни как не решает, тк пакеты выдаются все также по несколько десятков за секунду, и обрабатываются соответственно тоже практически одновременно.

Ну и собственно вопрос - как с этим бороться?)

Comment: tcp с точки зрения программы не разбит на пакеты. Ядро ОС передающей стороны буферизирует данные для более оптимальной отправки, а принимающая буферизирует при приеме (на случай например нарушения прихода кадров, что бы их потом выдать программе в правильном порядке). TCP просто не предназначен для таких задач. Хотя можно попробовать поиграться настройками через fcntl или что то подобное, на тему изменения размера буфера

Comment: Размер окна и  ask на каждый пакет. Вроде можно проставить для отдельного сокета. Посмотрите иоконтролы всякие. Есть код сервера и клиента?